# React: How does ESLint know when a useEffect dependency can be omitted?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

The `useEffect` hook of React normally requires every external value used to be added to the dependencies array. There seem to be a few exceptions, like the `setState` function given from the second array item of `useState`, or `dispatch` from `useReducer`.

From what I've read, this is because React guarantees that `setState` will never change, so ESLint doesn't feel the need to require it in the dependencies. But how does ESLint know this? Is there a way for me to specify something as never-changing and let ESLint pick this up and allow me to omit the "fake dependency"?

An example:

```
function useCustomHook() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  return [state, setState];
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [customState, setCustomState] = useCustomHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(true);
  }, []); // ESLint does NOT complain that setState is missing

  useEffect(() => {
    setCustomState(true);
  }, []); // ESLint DOES complain that setCustomState is omitted

  //...
}
```

`setState` and `setCustomState` above are virtually the same, so what triggers ESLint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React team maintains the [React hooks ESLint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks). This plugin is where the "smarts" you described are contained.

There's no simple way to add your own exceptions. I know there are plenty of cases where you know it's not needed, but it's best to just include your own functions as dependencies. If they are truly referentially stable, the diffing overhead is almost nothing. If they do change for any reason, you'll be glad it's listed as a dependency.

Comment: I suppose that means they "hard-coded" their own exceptions. Fair enough then. I was mostly looking to mimic some of this functionality by directly passing a reference through a hook. A "nice to have" but no big deal.

Comment: Correct. I know what you mean! However I suspect adding your own global exceptions could come back to bite in the long term with difficult to find bugs, when someone creates another custom hook with the same name but different semantics. So it's probably best as-is. It is a minor nuisance listing extra dependencies when we feel like we know what we're doing, but there's really no harm to it.